# TSP using Dynamic Programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am learning TSP and found this recursive solution to TSP

```
int compute(int start,int set)
{   int masked,mask,result=INT_MAX,temp,i;//result stores the minimum 
    if(g[start][set]!=-1)//memoization DP top-down,check for repeated subproblem
        return g[start][set];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {   //npow-1 because we always exclude "home" vertex from our set
            mask=(npow-1)-(1<<i);//remove ith vertex from this set
            masked=set&mask;
            if(masked!=set)//in case same set is generated(because ith vertex was not present in the set hence we get the same set on removal) eg 12&13=12
            {   
                temp=adj[start][i]+compute(i,masked);//compute the removed set
                if(temp<result)
                    result=temp,p[start][set]=i;//removing ith vertex gave us minimum
            }
        }
        return g[start][set]=result;//return minimum
}
```

I could not understand How masking is working , How can change it to Dynamic programming solution without using recursion , please help me.

Comment: This is already a top-down dynamic programming solution, you want to change it to bottom up form?

Comment: @PhamTrung could you please explain me !!! please

Comment: Hmm, what do you not understand? dynamic programming or bitmask?

Comment: `mask=(npow-1)-(1<<i)` ,  ` masked=set&mask;`
            `if(masked!=set)` why these line

Comment: how to make it none recursive , please help

Comment: @PhamTrung i will be very thankfully if you explain be both !!!!

Comment: Checking this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25681432/using-bitmasking-in-dynamic-programming/25682194#25682194) to have a better idea, I believe this and your question using same source code :)

Comment: if i make it non recursive how can i do it !!! i have tried too hard but i am not successful !!!

Comment: Hmm, you should solve easier dp problem, I think try to use two new different techniques at the same time is quite hard.

Comment: if you provide me pseudo code it will be quite helpful !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](http://poj.org/problem?id=3311) is a traditional TSP problem ,and here is the solution for it . I think it may be helpful to you.

```
int map[15][15];
int dp[(1<<12)+5][12];

int main() {
    int i,j,n,ans,k,p;
    while(1) {
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n==0) break;
        n++;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                scanf("%d",&map[i][j]);
            }
        }
        //floyd algorithm, get any two points's minimum distance
        for (k=0; k<n; k++) {
            for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
                for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
                    if (i!=j && i!=k && j!=k) map[i][j]=min(map[i][k]+map[k][j],map[i][j]);
                }
            }
        }
        memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
        dp[1][0]=0;
        // TSP solution here,bitmask and DP
        for (i=1; i<(1<<n); i++) {// the current state
            for (j=0; j<n; j++) {// during the current state,the last station is j
                if (dp[i][j]==-1) continue;
                for (k=1; k<n; k++) {//the next state is k
                    if ((i & (1<<k))!=0) continue;
                    p=(i | (1<<k));// the new state(join k)
                    if (dp[p][k]==-1) dp[p][k]=dp[i][j]+map[j][k];
                    dp[p][k]=min(dp[p][k],dp[i][j]+map[j][k]);
                }
            }
        }
        ans=INF;
        // get answer
        for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
            if (dp[(1<<n)-1][i]>0) ans=min(ans,dp[(1<<n)-1][i]+map[i][0]);
        }
        printf("%d\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this will ping you if i find some problem !!!!

Comment: `if (dp[(1<<n)-1][i]>0)` why this it is possible that one point is never a ending point

Comment: because there can be one or more points that I can't access,that is,this point(s) is dis-connected from other points.For example, points 1,2,3,4 are strong-connected but point 5 is away from them(there is no edge between 5 and other points),then in state 11111 and 5 is an ending point,this state can't be reached at all.